# Compilation error with \ifnum in ConTeXt

Tags: conditionals, context, math-operators, catcodes, mathcode

Why the following code gives me the following error?

Code:

```
\begingroup \catcode`\"=12
    \gdef\newmcodes@{\mathcode`\'39\mathcode`\*42\mathcode`\."613A%
    \ifnum\mathcode`\-=45 \else
        \mathchardef\std@minus\mathcode`\-\relax
    \fi
    \mathcode`\-45\mathcode`\/47\mathcode`\:"603A\relax}
\endgroup

\definemathcommand[xyz][nolop]{\newmcodes@\kern\zeropoint\mfunction{fancy-function-name'*.:}}

\starttext
$\xyz$
\stoptext
```

Error:

```
tex error       > error on line 13 in file /Users/maggyero/Desktop/test.tex: ! Extended mathchar used as mathchar (4203026)
<to be read again> 
=
\newmcodes ...thcode `\."613A\ifnum \mathcode `\-=
                                                  45 \else \mathchardef \std...
<argument> \newmcodes @
             \kern \zeropoint \mfunction {fancy-function-name'*.:}
\486>nolop #1->\mathop {#1
                          }\nolimits 
l.13 $\xyz
        $
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In any case the `@` is not a letter, so `\newmcodes @` are two tokens, and the same for `\std @minus`. You should add `\unprotect` and `\protect` before that code using `@` in control sequences.

Comment: I have to wonder what you are up to here: based on egreg's comment on his answer, you seem to have copy-pasted some of the  `amsmath` code for LaTeX into ConTeXt!

Comment: @JosephWright I think I saw a previows question, he's trying to replicate the behaviour of `\DeclareMathOperator` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Manuel: Exactly, it's copied from `amsopn.sty` to replicate the behaviour of `\DeclareMathOperator`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `@` in command names, when using ConTeXt; but you should be aware of the fact that ConTeXt uses Unicode math, so the standard math code of the hyphen cannot be accessed to with `\mathcode`.

```
\begingroup
  \catcode`\"=12 \catcode`\`=12 % added a safe setting for the backquote
  \gdef\newmcodes{\mathcode`\'39\mathcode`\*42\mathcode`\."613A
  \ifnum\Umathcodenum`\-=4203026 \else
    \Umathcharnumdef\stdminus\Umathcodenum`\-\relax
  \fi
  \mathcode`\-45\mathcode`\/47\mathcode`\:"603A\relax}
\endgroup

\definemathcommand[xyz][nolop]{\begingroup % added a grouping
  \newmcodes\kern\zeropoint\mfunction{fancy-function-name'*.:}%
  \endgroup}

\starttext
$\xyz$
\stoptext
```

I also added a safe setting for the backquote and grouping around the call of `\newmcodes`.

[image]

Comment: Code for the error is part of http://www.luatex.org/svn/tags/beta-0.76.0/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/mathcodes.w. Perhaps worth noting in the question that with LuaTeX/XeTeX the relationship `\mathcode`/`\mathchardef`/`\Umathcode`/... is complex (and could I guess still be revised somewhat).

Comment: The code is written in uselessly compressed way which complicates reading for humans. It is much more better to write ``\mathcode`\'=39 \mathcode`\*=42`` than ``\mathcode`\'39\mathcode`\*42``. Or instead ``\Umathcharnumdef\stdminus\Umathcodenum`\-\relax`` would be better to write ``\Umathcharnumdef\stdminus=\Umathcodenum`\-``. And the percent at the end of line two causes that the expanding of `\ifnum` is done before previous `\mathcode` is assigned.

Comment: @wipet You're right about the `%`, which I didn't notice in the original code`; I kept the OP's style with regard to assignments.

Comment: Yes, this is OP's style. But we can notice that this is not a good style.

Comment: @wipet I suspect (though I can't be sure) that the lack of `=` comes from some 'paranoid' code where no assumption is made about the catcode of `=`: you can avoid that worry by simply missing out the symbol entirely, after all.

Comment: @wipet Let's be honest, the original code is not exact perfect in many ways: for example, why have ``\catcode`\"=12``, why the weird `@` business (it's ConTeXt, so there should be `\unprotect` or perhaps `\donewmcodes`).

Comment: @JosephWright Macro writer cannot be paranoid about `=` catcode because the macro body is tokenized _before_ user can change its category. IMHO, the lack of `=` comes from old days where the computer memory was counted to kilobytes and each saved byte was usable. But no today when we have Gigabytes of memory.

Comment: @JosephWright It's copied from `amsopn.sty`; the code even has the improper `%` (which does no real harm in this case).

Comment: @egreg: Yes, it's copied from `amsopn.sty` to replicate the behaviour of `\DeclareMathOperator`. Thank you for the code. By the way, why does the mathcode of `.` is assigned `"613A` instead of `"602E`? (`1` stands for the *italic family* while `0` stands for the *roman family*, and `3A` stands for the *colon* while `2E` stands for the *full stop*). In other words, why are *full stops* converted into (mathcoded *italic*) *colons* in the `\DeclareMathOperator` of the `amsopn.sty`?

Comment: @Maggyero  The standard math code of the period is `"13A`; Knuth  decided that the period in math should come from the math italic font and placed it in the slot for the colon. About the above code: it works, but I believe it's definitely not standard ConTeXt code. And probably you should check the `Umathcodenum` for the period.